# How do i extract specific data (name, details )from the website into excel with excel vba?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

How do i extract specific data (name, details )from the website into excel with excel vba?

Below I am trying to get processor and warranty:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetData()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemELE As Object
    Dim html As IHTMLDocument
    Dim Processor As String
    Dim warranty As String
    Dim y As Integer

    'start a new browser instance
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make browser visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate "https://www.harveynorman.com.sg/computers-tablets-and-gaming/computers/laptops/"
    'wait for page to load
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    y = 1

    For Each itemELE In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("expandabaleContent")
        Processor = itemELE.getElementsByTagName("d1")(0).innerText
        warranty = itemELE.getElementsByClassName("d1")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).textContent

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = Processor
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = warranty
        y = y + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**Screenshot of the page:**

[image: Webpage]

Comment: What exactly is the issue you have? The only indication of a problem is the question title.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Please check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and also see "[ask]" as well as the [help/on-topic].  Please provide an explanation of what you have and what you're trying to do as well as what you've tried **and** why it hasn't work.  Only the minimal amount of code required to reproduced the problem should be included; see how to create a **[mcve]**.

Comment: @Comintern my data is not able to retrieve to data sheet. What is wrong with my code

Comment: There is no class called `expandabaleContent`, without or without what appears to be a typo. Nor is there information stored against d1 tag (should that be dl - which also isn't present). 1) Is this the right URL ? 2) Can you include a sample of expected output.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from which page you want processor & warranty info?

Comment: i want to auto retrieve and store the processor and warranty details into the excel cell

Comment: That I can see from your code ... can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 4):

For the page shown (**in your image**) you can issue an [XMLHTTP (XHR) GET request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) to grab the product info without opening a slow IE browser instance.

---

### **For the specific information:**

**Processor and warranty info:**

If you inspect the page the info about processor and warranty appears associated with a classname `facetedResults-feature-list`

[image: class]

You can see the classname and then a `dl` tag housing a `dt` tag which has sibling `dd` tags. Two of these sibling `dd` tags are associated with the info for processor and warranty.

I use a CSS selector to grab all these `dd` tags which can be simplified,in this instance, to ignore the sibling `dt` and parent `dl` tags and use just:

`.facetedResults-feature-list dd`

The `"."` is a [class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp). The CSS combination selection above says get the `dd` tags within elements with class `facetedResults-feature-list`

---

**Product titles info:**

The `titles` I get using another CSS selector of:

```
.facetedResults-title
```

This is elements with class `facetedResults-title`. This contains the product title.

[image: title]

---

**Writing out product titles, processor and warranty info to the sheet:**

A little maths shows me that the processor info repeats every 14, and that if I add 8 to the index for the processor I get the warranty info. You can see how you could write out **each** of the details as they occur at indices that repeat every 14. I combine the loop over the nodeList of `dd` elements with the `titles` to write out to the sheet.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.lenovo.com/sg/en/laptops/c/LAPTOPS", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Dim titles As Object, targetedInfo As Object, rowCounter As Long
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".facetedResults-title")
        Set targetedInfo = .querySelectorAll(".facetedResults-feature-list dd")
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To targetedInfo.Length - 1
            If i Mod 14 = 0 Then
                rowCounter = rowCounter + 1
                .Cells(rowCounter, 1) = titles(rowCounter - 1).innerText
                .Cells(rowCounter, 2) = targetedInfo(i).innerText
                .Cells(rowCounter, 3) = targetedInfo(i + 8).innerText
            End If
        Next i          
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Output sample:**

[image: output sample]

---

### **More general info:**

**CSS selectors:**

The product info is associated with an `'expandableContent facetedResults-expandableContent-features expandableContent-is-collapsed facetedResults-expandableContent-69'` class name

The prices are associated with an `'expandableContent facetedResults-expandableContent-price expandableContent-is-collapsed'`  class name.

You can select these by the traditional `.getElementsByClassName` and then loop over the collection, or, in my case, use a CSS selector for class to do the same thing, and then traverse the length of the returned `nodeList`.

```
.getElementsByClassName("expandableContent facetedResults-expandableContent-features expandableContent-is-collapsed facetedResults-expandableContent-69")
```

is the same as

```
.querySelectorAll(".expandableContent.facetedResults-expandableContent-features.expandableContent-is-collapsed.facetedResults-expandableContent-69")
```

The `"."` is the [class selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp).

Titles are associated with a class `facetedResults-title`

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, i As Long, html As New HTMLDocument
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.lenovo.com/sg/en/laptops/c/LAPTOPS", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))
    Dim info As Object, prices As Object, titles As Object
    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Set titles = .querySelectorAll(".facetedResults-title")
        Set info = .querySelectorAll(".expandableContent.facetedResults-expandableContent-features.expandableContent-is-collapsed.facetedResults-expandableContent-69")
        Set prices = .querySelectorAll(".expandableContent.facetedResults-expandableContent-price.expandableContent-is-collapsed")
    End With
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 0 To titles.Length - 1
            .Cells(i + 1, 1) = titles(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 1, 2) = info(i).innerText
            .Cells(i + 1, 3) = prices(i).innerText
        Next i
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**References required (VBE>Tools>References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: well covered... I upvoted to ensure the question won't be put on hold

Answer (score 2):

Qharr has already provided some good options but in case still you want to try IE then see below code

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetData()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim itemELE As Object
    Dim html As IHTMLDocument
    Dim Processor As String
    Dim warranty As String
    Dim y As Integer

    'start a new browser instance
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    'make browser visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate to page with needed data
    objIE.navigate "https://www.lenovo.com/sg/en/laptops/c/LAPTOPS"
    'wait for page to load

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)


    y = 1


    For Each itemELE In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("facetedResults-feature-list")

        If InStr(1, itemELE.className, "bundleList", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
            Processor = itemELE.getElementsByTagName("dl")(0).innerText
            warranty = itemELE.getElementsByTagName("dl")(4).innerText

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = Processor
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = warranty
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Nice as usual :-)